# C++ Using the operator keyword with a template?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

I'm stuggling with defining friend operator functions.  My code is as follows:

```
    template <typename typ>
    class VecClass 
    {
     public:
        VecClass();
        /* other class definitions */
        friend void operator+(VecClass op1,VecClass op2);
    }

    template <typename typ>
    void VecClass<typ>::operator+(VecClass<typ> &op1,VecClass<typ> &op2)
    {
        /* do some stuff on op1 and op2 in here */
    }
```

where VecClass is a class to create vectors and perform various functions on those vectors (N.B. I've simplified the code to try and be as clear as possible). When compiling, using

```
    int main()
    {
        VecClass=a,b;
        a+b;
        return 0;
    }
```

I get the following compilation error

```
     error C2039: '+' : is not a member of 'VecClass<typ>'
```

I'm clearly missing something and would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanx.

Comment: A `friend` function isn't a member function.

Answer (score 6):

You declared a friend operator, not class member, so remove `VecClass<typ>::`

```
template <typename typ>
void operator+(VecClass<typ> &op1,VecClass<typ> &op2)
{
        /* do some stuff on op1 and op2 in here */
}
```

Comment: Or you can remove `friend` keyword aswell.

Comment: In either case, take note that the signatures aren't matching: the friend declaration takes objects, the template definition takes references.

Comment: @ChristianStieber: Indeed. And the best choice is neither of them; it's a const reference.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: It`s not help. Operator + is binary function, not ternary. If you remove friend keyword, signature of this operator must be VecClass operator +(const VecClass&);

Comment: Thanx for all answers and comments, which helped me arrive at a solution. I was getting bogged down in implementing a friend operator that included a template typename, when I really should be specifying the typename in the friend definition - otherwise I could be trying to apply the operator to objects of different types. For example, for a particular overloaded operator I now have: `friend VecClass<double> operator+(const double a,VecClass<double> &rhs);` and the definition `VecClass<double> operator+(const double a,const VecClass<double> &rhs{...}`.